# Logstash 5 Alpha4 to elasticsearch5 Alpha4 communication error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Elasticsearch 5 is secured with xpack security and hooked with ldap which is working fine. Even user has admin right in `role_mapping`.

Logstash 5 configuration is as below

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ['localhost:9200']
    user => 'gaurav@gmail.com'
    password => 'pwd'
  }
}
```

Getting below error and because of which logstash is not able to pass data to elasticsearch.

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-07-14T16:32:29.592000+0530", 
:message=>"Encountered an unexpected error submitting a bulk request! Will retry.", 
:error_message=>"undefined method code' for #", 
:class=>"NoMethodError", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-4.1.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:217:insafe_bulk'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-4.1.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:105:in submit'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-4.1.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:72:inretrying_submit'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-4.1.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:23:in multi_receive'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1653:ineach_slice'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-4.1.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:22:in multi_receive'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:136:inthreadsafe_multi_receive'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_
```

Comment: This is happening for me on ES 5.1 and logstash 5.1.

Comment: Can you run logstash with `--debug` and provide the full log please?

Comment: Does this happen on startup right away? Also, are you seem to be using the 4.4.1 output for ES 5 or am I just confused by the log? Looking at a freshly downloaded Logstash 5.1.1, the output plugin version should be 5.4.0 not 4.1.1

Comment: @pandaadb, that is OP's log message. I just added the bounty because I was running into the same, and not making much progress. I have since realized that I was using the 4.5.0 version of the elasticsearch-output plugin. This was not on purpose... it seems to be the default that is packaged with the 5.1.1 version of logstash.

Comment: @Brad reason i pointed that out is that with other tools (e.g. client on python/java etc) it is noted many times that the version of the client used MUST match the version of ES used. Using any 2 non-matching versions will always run the risk of having weird bugs. For OP this might just be an accident/oversight since he is using beta. Why your 5.1 is running the wrong version is a mystery though and might be worth raising with either the alpine docker image or the logstash team

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have figured it out. I am using the Logstash 5.1.1-alpine docker image. As far as I can tell, it comes with the elasticsearch-output plugin v4.5.0, which seems to have this bug. Forcing an update of that plugin to the latest (6.2) has fixed this issue.

My Dockerfile now

```
FROM logstash:5.1.1-alpine

RUN $LOGSTASH_PATH/logstash-plugin install --version 6.2.0 logstash-output-elasticsearch
```

With the updated plugin, I no longer see this error.